# What does this phrase "hover around" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

**"Until the late 1800s, diamonds were incredibly scarce with the total world production hovering around a few pounds per year"** 
What does the phrase "hover around" mean in that sentence?

Comment: Incidentally, there should be a comma after *scarce*.

Comment: Have you looked up the word 'hover' and all its meanings?

Answer (score 3):

"**Hover around**" literally means to fly around something.
Here, in this sentence, it means that the amount of diamond production kept fluctuating around a few pounds, i.e. sometimes it decreased a little from a few pounds per year, and  sometimes it increased from the same amount.

Comment: I think "around" in "hover around" usually means "approximately" in the sense of hovering at an approximate height, as compared to flying around something. This also fits the meaning about diamond production.

Answer (score 2):

to **hover around**  [MacMilland](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/hover)

> to be at or near a particular level without changing much, to hover
>   around/near

As in:

> Their total world sales hover around the 50,000,000 mark.